# How to isolate login logic in a separate DbContext with .NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-identity

I'm creating a mobile app for user with an analytics dashboard for business. I currently have two APIs:

1. The main API, to manage user resources.
2. The business API to query analytics about the users resources.

My problem is that I'm trying to create a single Authentification API. I want the login logic to be **independent** from other two API's. The flow that I see is:

User or business log in -> LOGIN API -> Generate Token with claim of AccountType.

I'd like to also have three separate DbContext with the two others linked to CredentialsDBContext

```cs
public class User {
       public Credentials Credentials {get; set;} // CredentialsDBContext 
       public Shirts Shirts {get; set;} // MainDbContext
}
```

How can I do this, knowing that you can't create have two DBContext in a single class?

Answer (score 0):

happily you are not the first one who wants to this! actually this is the approach most of the server-side apps take.

There is a protocol called `OAuth2.0` with `OpenId Connect` which help you to completely separate user authentication/authorization from your business logic.

There are popular libraries that do this job for you like :

- [IdentityServer4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjOm5urlZbkAhXqpVkKHQSTCi8QFjADegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FIdentityServer%2FIdentityServer4&usg=AOvVaw20Kcqlb5OWUUaoHRDOHrKl)
- [OpenIddict](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiL6dW7lZbkAhUCvlkKHasmAgQQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fopeniddict%2Fopeniddict-core&usg=AOvVaw3fLeurwLmRBHkbCLBIbzcs)
- and much more

Also it worth to note that you can have multiple DbContexts in your project and they can also point to the same database, but that way it may be hard to create the database using `Code First` approach and you may need to create it manually.